# why can't I put switch statement in the class

Tags: c++, console-application

I have problem with switch statement in class Birthday, why can't i put switch in the class?
i try to solve but i can't, i use visual studio 2017

This is Error List image
[image]

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Birthday {
public:
    Birthday(int d,int m,int y) 
        :day(d),month(m),year(y)
    {
    }
    void printBirth() {
        cout << month << " " << day << " " << year << endl;
    }

private:
    int day, month, year;
    string month_name;
    switch (month)
    {
    case 1:
        month_name = "January"
            break;
    default:
        month = "None";
        break;
    }

};
```

Comment: If that were possible: when should the code be executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the code / [statements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) representing executable code should be placed inside member function (body), not in arbitrary class scope. [Class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) is (a user defined) type. It is data and functionality on that data wrapped into one. The functionality goes inside a member function.

Answer (score 3):

Classes don't contain executable statements, they contain *member functions* (also known as *methods*), which can contain statements. One of those functions is a special case known as the *constructor*, which you've actually used in your example.

If you want to do something like assigning a variable based on some other field, you can do it inside the constructor:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Birthday {
public:
    Birthday(int d,int m,int y) 
        :day(d),month(m),year(y)
    {
        switch (month)
        {
        case 1:
            month_name = "January"
                break;

        // Add remaining cases here
        default:
            month_name = "None";
            break;
        }
    }
    void printBirth() {
        cout << month << " " << day << " " << year << endl;
    }

private:
    int day, month, year;
    string month_name;


};
```

Note that I also fixed your assignment of `month = "None";` - `month` is an `int`, you need to assign to `month_name` instead.

Answer (score -1):

No statement like "switch, if, elseif etc." can be used the way you did. You can write declarative stuff inside class scope like variables and function declarations, but not actual code body, this is the reason you must write it inside your member function's scope.